# 404 Error on .woff, .woff2 and .ttf fonts for a React application deployed in a production shared IIS host

Tags: reactjs, iis, http-status-code-404, font-awesome, shared-hosting

The mimetypes already exist in the IIS settings initially.

[image]

I also have tried adding the mimetypes in the web.config file but still not working.

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
```

I also tried adding the request filtering and still not working.

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
            <add fileExtension=".woff" allowed="true" />
            <add fileExtension=".ttf" allowed="true" />
            <add fileExtension=".woff2" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

[image]

[image]

I appreciate your help. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that the file location requested in the URL is incorrect, so please verify that the file requested in the browser's URL exists on the IIS computer and that it is in the correct location.

you can use the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in to determine where the file requested must exist in the IIS computer's file system.

More information you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-404-file-not-found-error#resolution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to IIS computer. I have tried copying these files to root and almost all sub folders but still not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is difficult to solve your problem without permission.